# Можно ли определить набор необходимых библиотек для ехе без его загрузки?

Tags: c#, dll

Есть несколько различных .net запускаемых файлов. Можно ли, не загружая их, узнать, какие библиотеки будут загружены при его работе? Точнее, какие References имел его проект, если смотреть как будто бы из VisualStudio?

Comment: Посмотрите что Dependency Walker показывает про его импорты. В общем случае, разумеется, задача не решаема из-за возможности динамического импорта.

Comment: В-общем, да. Но интересует именно references исходного проекта

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно. Используйте [ILDasm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa309387%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/), [dotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/). Открываете в них exe файл и в разделе References смотрите, на какие сборки он ссылается (скриншот из dotPeek):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Программно получить список зареференсенных сборок можно так:

```
var assembly = Assembly.LoadFile("MyApp.exe");
foreach (var reference in assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies())
{
    Console.WriteLine(reference.FullName);
}
```

Для более глубокого анализа удобнее использовать библиотеку [Mono.Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil):

```
var assembly = AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(assemblyFilePath);
foreach (var reference in assembly.MainModule.AssemblyReferences)
{
    Console.WriteLine(reference.FullName);
}
```

Comment: а собственную реализацию можно в .Net сделать? Например, для того, чтобы собрать статистику о нескольких разных приложениях и в зависимости от результата выполнить какие-то операции?
куда копать не пойму... это вроде как метаданные? можно их вытащить для анализа через сам .net?

Comment: @kvvk обновил ответ.